# JDialog before a JFrame

Tags: java

I am implementing the game "Wheel of Fortune" using java.
Before I display the main window, I need to first create a dialog and read in player informations from users so that I can use these information to set up my main window.

The main function code looks like (restricted by instructor):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    WheelOfFortuneFrame gameFrame = new WheelOfFortuneFrame();
    gameFrame.pack();
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

So I can only add code in the constructor of WheelOfFortuneFrame.
What I am trying to do is creating a JDialog in the constructor of Wheelof ForturneFrame, like this:

```
public class WheelOfFortuneFrame extends JFrame(){

 // Some member variables
 private numberofPlayers = 0;

 public WheelOfFortuneFrame() {
    super("Wheel of Fortune");

    SetDialog = new SetupDialog(null);
    SetDialog.setVisible(true);

    // Things for the main window
 }
}
```

I tried to change the member variables of WheelOfFortuneFrame class in the Dialog, like:

```
public final class SetupDialog extends JDialog{

    public SetupDialog(JFrame mainframe){
       .......
       numberofVariables = InputField.getText();
    }
}
```

But I found that I failed to change member variables of WheelOfFortuneFrame before the constructing of it, which means I cannot use user-input value to construct my main window.

Comment: Can you confirm of clarify: You won't to display a JDialog from the constructor of the WheelofFortune class (which is a subclass of JFrame)?

Comment: I edit the question, it should look more clear now. What I am trying to do is to change the member variables of main class before actually constructing it, so that the user-input value from JDialog can be used to construct the main window.

Comment: Have you considered using [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: Can JOptionPane achieve the purpose that: First prompts the use for some information, then use these information to construct the main frame? ( main frame appears after JOptionPane disappears)

Comment: Yes. `JOptionPane` can have a "null" parent and can collect and return data entered by the user once it is closed. Then you can use that data in other parts of your code. What details do you initially require? Is it the number of players in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the `WheelOfFortuneFrame` variables from the `SetupDialog` class. However, you can do the following:

1. Add a `numberOfPlayers` variable and a `getNumberOfPlayers() { return numberOfPlayers; }` function to the `SetupDialog` class.
2. Setup this variable from the `InputField` *inside* the `SetupDialog` class.
3. In the `WheelOfFortuneFrame` constructor, after `SetDialog.setVisible(true)` returns do `numberOfPlayers = SetDialog.getNumberOfPlayers();`

Here is a short example that shows a dialog before a frame is displayed. Note that using a `JOptionPane` instead of a hand-crafted dialog may be more convenient.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public final class DialogBeforeFrame extends JFrame {
   /** Dialog that prompts for a single string as input. */
   private static class SetupDialog extends JDialog {
      final JTextField input;
      public SetupDialog() {
         super();
         setModal(true);
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         input = new JTextField("Some text");
         add(input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Ok") {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  setVisible(false);
               }
            }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      }
      public String getInput() { return input.getText().trim(); }
   }

   /** Constructor that takes the text to display as argument. */
   public DialogBeforeFrame(String text) {
      super();
      add(new JLabel(text));
   }
   /** Constructor that shows a dialog which prompts for the text to be displayed. */
   public DialogBeforeFrame() {
      super();

      final SetupDialog dialog = new SetupDialog();
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setVisible(true);

      add(new JLabel(dialog.getInput()));
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = null;

      // Two variants of constructing the frame:
      // 1. We first show the dialog, extract the configuration from the dialog
      //    and then construct the frame with these arguments.
      // 2. We have the frame's constructor show a dialog for configuration.
      if ( false ) {
         final SetupDialog dialog = new SetupDialog();
         dialog.pack();
         dialog.setVisible(true);

         frame = new DialogBeforeFrame(dialog.getInput());
      }
      else {
         frame = new DialogBeforeFrame();
      }

      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);
            }
         });
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Now I do things like  you said.                                                                                                                                Still,  after I run, the main window appears before the Jdialog prompts the use for answers. What I really want is to first prompt the use for some information, then set up the main windows according to these information. The important thing is, the main frame appears after JDialog finishes. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can't you just show the `JDialog` from the `main` function? I.e., add something like this to the top of your `main()`: `SetDialog = new SetupDialog(null); SetDialog.setVisible(true);` and then pass the data from `SetDialog` as arguments to the `WheelOfFortuneFrame` constructor?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a short code that works (for me).